# Rails 4.1 Create Page When Link Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nfc

I have a rather unique question that probably has a simple answer but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I am using rails 4.1 and creating an app that I want to accept urls that don't exist as part of a NFC tag registration process.

For example, let's say the app is located at example.com and I programmed an NFC tag with the url example.com/xyz123.

I don't want the rails app to spit out a 404 error but rather attribute that tag to the signed in User account and allow them to register that url to one of that users' personalized pages that they created.

I've dug into the docs on error handling but that doesn't seem to solve the problem and I can't seem to find where in the core API these requests are handled and how I might override them in the application.rb controller.

Comment: Could it be that you have not defined the routes in your routes.rb files. It seems like the url you are trying to access is not found and so it goes to 404 error. It you have some controller, place the code like, get '/xyz123' => 'page#index'. Or if you want this to be custom url then rather try it as get '/:someparameter' => 'page#index'

Comment: I don't want to pre-register any tag routes in the app. Rather, when they come off the line they will have an alphanumeric url route encoded in them. I want to capture the error generated by going to example.com/xyz123 and register the url to a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is rather simple. just create a catch-all route

```
get '*path', to: 'tags#new'
```

the requested part will be `params[:path]`

i would recommend not having unscoped catch-all routes through. it's slow and a pita if you ever want to change your URL structure (you will want to do that at some point). always use some namespace `www.some-url.com/t/xyz123`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew it was something simple, just one of those days.